# How do I get php7.2 to be default?

Tags: php, version

I have followed several different threads in order to Disable php7.4 and enable php7.2 but when I enter php -v it still shows php7.4 information.
What I have done:
a2dismod php7.4 (message says "Module php7.4 already disabled")
a2enmod php7.2 (message says "Module php7.2 already enabled") 
but php -v still gives info about php7.4

Is that the correct response even if php7.2 is enabled?
My apologies for not providing enough info: Ubuntu 19.10 on a vps 
I also created a phpinfo file and it shows to be using 7.2 so I guess everything is working as it should, I was just confused why the command line was still showing info from 7.4.

Thanks

Comment: that depends on your os, `which php` will tell you where php is, you may be looking for removing php7.4, maybe something like `sudo apt remove php7.4`

Comment: You can just use `php7.2` to specifically use the php 7.2 executable

Comment: `but when I enter php -v it still shows php7.4 information` ... is this hosted or local? What OS are you using. What development environment are you using and version? .... Too many few details are going to get you nowhere fast on SO. (I upvoted to bring this question some attention)

Comment: If you are doing `php -v` that means you are using the PHP CLI. Thats not controlled by `a2enmod` as that is switching versions in Apache only